# Properties detail are missing from VertexLabel using JanusGraphManagement API

Tags: java, cassandra, gremlin, janusgraph

I am using janugraph 1.0.0 and using cassandra as backend storage.This is configuration file with cassandra details,  janusgraph-cql/.properties

[cassandra config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUSrB.png)

Now using gremlin console, I have added vertex and I am able to fetch it .
[gremlin console vertex insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy5o7.png)

Now on trying to get the properties and the datatype, using JanusGraphManagemnet API.
[fetch via mangaemnet API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQdOl.png)

I am unable to get the property details , Is there any way to get the details using management API ?